# c++ argument changes in thread function

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, android-ndk, arguments

I'm writing an Android application which reads a text file in c++ (NDK).

I copy the file `list` from `assets` folder to `/data/user/0/my-package/files/list` where I can read with my native code, after the copy is done or if the destination file is exist, I do the following:

```
const char* fileName = env->GetStringUTFChars(_name, nullptr);
const char* filePath = env->GetStringUTFChars(_destination, nullptr);
if(copy_file(AAssetManager_fromJava(env, manager),fileName, filePath)){
    Reader *r = new Reader();
    log("Initializing reader with file: %s",filePath);
    thread t(&Reader::read, r, filePath);
    t.detach();// will crash if no detach, join() will block the UI thread.
}
```

And my `Reader::read`:

```
void Reader::read(const char* filePath){
    log("Reading from file: %s",filePath);
    ifstream infile(filePath);
    string line;
    while(infile>>line){
        // read logic ...
    }
}
```

I get different output, some times

```
Initializing reader with file: /data/user/0/my-package/files/list
Reading from file: /data/user/0/my-package/files/list
```

and everything works as expected. **But** some times I get

```
Initializing reader with file: /data/user/0/my-package/files/list
Reading from file: /data/user/0/my-package/files
```

see? It seems that the file path is cut somehow, and my `ifstream` is trying to read the directory `files`.

I was told that the argument `filePath` will be passed to the thread by value by default, and there's no other thread working with the variable, only thing that happens to `filePath` after the thread initialization, is:

```
  env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(_destination, filePath);
```

I have tried many different ways to pass the file path to new thread, if I pass the `filePath` like
`std::ref(filePath)`, I will get empty string in `read` function, because the variable is already cleared outside.

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: What is `destination`?

Comment: @user253751 is a `const char*`

Comment: Note quite enough code, but smells like a race condition with what ever `destination` is referencing going out off scope / being reused.  The thread constructor only copies the pointer not what is pointed to.  How is `destination` initialised and what happens to the buffer it points to after the thread is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling ReleaseStringUTFChars before the thread has finished will be disastrous, since the memory that **filePath** points too will be freed. If you don't fully understand how pointers and memory handling works, I suggest using something like **std::string** instead of **const char***, and pass that string to your function.

Comment: As I mentioned at the end of my post, if I pass it by reference like `std:ref(filePath)`, it will get freed, and I will get an empty string in my `read` function, I guess this is what you are talking about. But if I pass it directly, I will get **a part of** the `filePath`, I mean, if my approach is disastrous, why I get `/data/user/0/my-package/files` **every time this happens** but not something else? why the file name is missing?

Comment: @WALKER Use-after-free results in undefined behavior. Pretty much anything can happen.

Comment: @Michael So, if this is where the problem lies, isn't my `filePath` passed by value?

Comment: Yes, the pointer itself is passed by value, but the memory (=the actual string) that it points to is passed by reference.